# Python UnicodeDecodeError | Encoding doesn't seem to work

Tags: python, unicode

Trying to send emails to emails inside of a json file.
Set up very simple code to do this but I am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3039: character maps to <undefined>`

```
import smtplib
import ssl
import glob
import json

message = "foo"

file_list = glob.glob("mongo/*.json")
used_list = list()
context = ssl.create_default_context()
amount = 0

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("mailserver", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.login("username", "password")
    with open("mongo/sellix.json") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        for order in data:
            email = order['customer_email'].encode('utf8')
            if email not in used_list:
                server.sendmail("my_email", email, message)
                amount == 1
                print(f"Sent out another email... [{str(amount)}]")
                used_list.append(email)
```

I've tried the following:

1. `str(order['customer_email'])`
2. `order['customer_email'].encode('utf8', errors='strict')`
3. `order['customer_email'].encode('utf8).decode('utf8')`
4. and about any other solution I could find

Comment: Please attach the value of `order['customer_email']`.

Comment: it's just an email `"customer_email": "p***st196@gmail.com"` edited out some characters but they were all standard characters no accents or any other "weird" chars.

Comment: So, if you can see this as a string, what's the problem?

Comment: well this is the problem: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 3039: character maps to <undefined> `

Comment: When do you receive this error exactly? Please elaborate. If customer_email is a normal string, as you wrote in your answer, you obviously don't need to decrypt it. This error wouldn't pop for a normal string

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: Getting it when `server.sendmail("my_email", email, message)` is called. `email (=order['customer_email'])` seems to be the problem

Comment: Python 3.8 @mhawke

Comment: Try to check if all of the chars inside your string answer to RFC-822 standard

Comment: I don't see why not as when I copy the string and paste it into the server.sendmail() it works just fine

Comment: Perhaps the console doesn't print all of the charcaters, and when you copy the value you lose the problematic characters

Comment: That could be a possibility but it seems very unlikely as I got the emails from my ecommerce shop & they also send out emails (to the same email addresses). It seems unlikely to me they added any problematic characters into it

Comment: Could ypu please provide some hard data that exhibits the problem? You can see by all the comments that everyone is guessing. Please include the email address (dump one of your JSON orders, redacted if necessary) and the _exact_ contents of `message`.

Comment: `"customer_email": "pabist196@gmail.com",` - the first email which also starts giving errors

for the `message` its just `message = "foo"`

Comment: The message must be an ASCII string, or a byte string. It will be encoded as ASCII, and that's probably where it's going wrong. 0x81 is out of the ASCII range.

Comment: Try to check if `email=="pabist196@gmail.com"`. If not, look for the index where they get different and trim the string accordingly.

Another option that you may try is checking for each char if it's ASCII and if not, remove it from the string

Comment: I have no idea why but after removing .encode() alltogether and copying the json file somewhere  and then pasting it back in it seemed to have fixed this

Comment: Encoding/decoding should never be necessary if the configuration is correct.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#python

Comment: Always post the **full** traceback of the error.  What line fails?  My guess is you didn't explicitly specify the encoding of the JSON file, e.g. `with open("mongo/sellix.json",encoding='utf8') as f:` and the default wasn't correct.